# Why does salt & pepper noise=0 change the image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, watermark, svd, dwt

I have an RGB image 512x512, and a 64x64 Watermark image which embedded with DWT, SVD.

watermarked image is 512x512 and double.
extracted image is good (bit error rate=0).

But when I use `imnoise` with `d=0`, the extracted image is not good and BER=58%!

What is causing this and how can I prevent this error?

```
watermarked_image_attack=double(imnoise(uint8(Watermarked_Image),'salt & pepper', 0));
Recovered_message=Extracting_attacked_image(watermarked_image_attack,'db1',0.05);
```

Comment: You convert to `uint8`, likely destroying most information in the image.

Comment: If you want more help than this, you’ll have to include a [mre].

Comment: converted to uint8 because imnoise accept just uint8.

Comment: That is not true. The documentation says “imnoise expects pixel values of data type double and single to be in the range [0, 1]. You can use the rescale function to adjust pixel values to the expected range. If your image is type double or single with values outside the range [0,1], then imnoise clips input pixel values to the range [0, 1] before adding noise.”